# Is there an easy and efficient way to delay a response from a Java Servlet

Tags: java, security, servlets, denial-of-service

What can I do when I get an obvious hacking attempt? I wish there was an easy way to cause them to waste their time, that doesn't involve server resources. Even a delay of a few seconds could render brute force attacks futile.

Sending them to an AsyncContext seems too processor intensive, and a timeout will automatically resend the same request back to the beginning where it started. Which might actually aide a DOS attack.

I am using Jetty and know about the DoSFilter, but it would be much more effective if I could delay a response when I detect foul play, which is rather easy to sense in my case. I think every failed validation / authentication attempt should automatically delay a response somehow.

I am not really authenticating here, so an authentication protocol/frontend is not useful. I am just validating the connection parameters for patterns that meet certain criteria. I know TCP/IP will notify, but if I could disconnect invalid access attempts silently and keep them hanging, that would be ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that, if you detect a fool play, it would be more wise to block their ip for a certain period. It would be easy just adding their ip in `/etc/hosts.deny` (it works for many unix daemons, but I am not sure if it works with java processes too, I think it *should work* since it's used by the tcp daemon itself). `man 5 hosts.deny` at the command line gives some hints (or check [this online link](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl5_hostsde.htm)).

BTW, I think you can use [`Thread.sleep()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29) to pause a servlet, as in any normal java code. But this, would probably cause more request from the same caller to keep open for long time, increasing the active resources that the application server has to allocate and maintain. So if the attacker can work in multithread, possibly this will help him to block your server, as it will hold all the threads for his attack, blocking all other users to access your service.

Comment: Thanks, your comment gave me an idea. I will look into adding abusive IPs to a filter layer for a time, such as nginx (mentioned by @Dims). I need to see if there is a way to do so on the fly, from the servlet itself.

Comment: that would probably work, if you immediately drop the connection. But still the attacker will consume a lot of your appserver resources. While having that on a firewall (as suggested by Dims) or in /etc/hosts.deny, would most likely be much more effective.

Comment: Is that /etc/hosts deny read dynamically by the OS? or does it require a restart/reset of some kind.

Comment: Yes, the effect is immediate. I used it before, to block unauthorized access to ssh, using a java program parsing from a the ssh error log. Changing the file has immediate effect.

Comment: In that case, it sounds like the easier and less CPU intensive of the solutions. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

If you get a suspiciously repetitive request from the same IP, you can introduce an escalating delay:

```
Thread.sleep(n);
```

Where n doubles every subsequent event.

Comment: I was wondering about that, but does't it tie up a thread? I thought that the HTTPServlet was served from a thread pool consisting of a limited number of threads. So if it does tie up a thread, could a multithreaded attack exhaust the pool and shut down the servlet? 

If it doesn't tie up a thread, then that would be so easy that I feel embarrassed for even asking the question!

Comment: Definitely don't `sleep` in a server thread. You are right that it will block the thread, eventually exhausting the pool and resulting in a successful DOS attack.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik totally disagree. depends what you are trying to prevent. If its password cracking, then this will work.  For DOS attacks, that can be, and is best, handled by switching hardware ignoring request floods, way before it even gets to the servlet.

Comment: Compare the `Thread.sleep` approach with `AsyncContext` and you'll see that there can't possibly be any advantage to `Thread.sleep`.

Answer (score 1):

I actually think that an AsyncContext may be a better solution than sleeping on a synchronous request.

However, I think you'd have to try both scenarios, and actually measure what each does to both cpu usage and total throughput to be sure.

Comment: No surprises awaiting: synchronous blocking will occupy a thread, which is a heavy system resource, regardless of whether the thread occupies any CPU. `Thread.sleep` is definitely the last thing one should resort to in a web server.

Answer (score 1):

You should protect at lower level. Any involvement of Java will damage you more than hackers, because container will create environment on each request.

Most probably hackers do not wait for response so you won't hit them by delaying it.

Use `nginx` or firewall level.

Comment: A front end sounds interesting, but it would have to be able to inspect the request and determine if its is valid or not. I will look into nginx to see what it can do, thanks.

Comment: I wonder now if I can just take an abusive IP and block it by adding it to a list in such a filter. I need to see if there any way to dynamically block an IP using that front end In other words, having the back-end dynamically configure the front-end when abused.

Comment: I have to give the answer to @Luigi R. Viggiano for presenting the simpler solution this time. But I am still glad to learn about nginx. I am going to study it some more. It sounds like it may be ideal for larger scale operations. Hopefully, I will get there someday. Thanks for your help.